# Load sprites from persistent data path

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am downloading some sprites from my server and store them in `Application.persistentDataPath`.

However, I cannot load the controller using `Resources.Load (controllerPath)` because the path is outside the Resources folder.

Additionally, I get a `MissingComponentException` when I try to add the animation controller to the `GameObject`.

Here is my code:

```
private GameObject SideSprite;

// ...

string controllerPath = Application.persistentDataPath+"/"+aux+"/"+aux+"Controller";
controller = (RuntimeAnimatorController)Resources.Load (controllerPath);  // Returns null

// Below I get:
// MissingComponentException: There is no 'Animator' attached to the
// "Missing Prefab (Dummy)" game object, but a script is trying to access it.
SideSprite.GetComponent<Animator> ().runtimeAnimatorController = controller;
```

How should I load the resources from the persistent data path?

Answer (score 2):

persistentDataPath is used as any regular folder. I would not store a Sprite but more likely a texture and next time you need it you unroll the process of applying a texture to a sprite:

```
public static void StoreCacheSprite(string url, Sprite sprite)
{
    if(sprite == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(url) == true) { return; }
    SpriteRenderer spRend = sprite.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    Texture2D tex = spRend.material.mainTexture;
    byte[] bytes = tex.EncodeToPNG();
    string path = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, url);
    File.WriteAllBytes(Application.persistentDataPath, bytes);
}
public static Sprite GetCacheSprite(string url)
{
    if( string.IsNullOrEmpty(url) == true) { return; }
    string path = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, url);
    if(File.Exists(path) == true)
    {
        bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(4, 4, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);
        texture.LoadImage(bytes);
        Sprite sp = Sprite.Create(texture, new Rect(0,0 texture.width, texture.height, new Vector2(0.5f,0.5f));
        return sp;
    }
    return null;
}
```

The first method stores the texture using the File class from .NET. It converts and writes a byte array onto the ROM of the device (File.WriteAllBytes). You need a path to a Sprite and a name for it. That name needs to comply with file and folder path naming.

The second method does the inverse process, checking if it is already stored and turning the byte array found on the RAM into a usable Sprite.

Answer (score 0):

You could also simply use WWW to get the data.

```
string controllerPath = Application.persistentDataPath+"/"+aux+"/"+aux+"Controller";
    IEnumerator Start ()
    {
        WWW www = new WWW("file:///" + controllerPath);
        yield return www;
        Debug.Log(www.texture); //or www.bytes
    }
```